# model.fit(...) and "Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor"

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm using TensorFlow 2.0 for text classification.

The structure of the data looks more-or-less like this:

#### 1st Approach:

```py
x: List[List[int]] # list of sentences consisting of a list of word IDs for each word in the sentence
y: List[int] # binary truth indicator
```

However, when calling `model.fit(...)` I receive the following error message:

`Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {'(<class \'list\'> containing values of types {"<class \'int\'>"})', "(<class 'list'> containing values of types set())"}), <class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Despite not using `set` anywhere.

#### 2nd Approach:

I tried using a numpy array for the inner list as follows:

```py
x: List[np.ndarray[np.int32]]
y: np.ndarray[np.int32]
```

But I received the following error:

`Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 32 input samples and 479 target samples.`

#### 3rd Approach:

This prompted me to change the data structure to:

```py
x: np.ndarray[np.ndarray[np.int32]]
y: np.ndarray[np.int32]
```

This resulted in the following error:

`Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).`

#### 4th Approach :

Trying,

```py
x: np.ndarray[List[int]]
y: np.ndarray[int]
```

Resulted in the following, similar error message:

`Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).`

#### TLDR;

So the question is: What's going on? Why won't `model.fit(...)` accept these parameters?

See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The reason I've documented this mess is that the underlying problem isn't related to the error messages.

The underlying problem is that the input data (`x`) requires padding.

Sentences naturally have varying lengths. TensorFlow's `model.fit(...)` does not like that. To get it to play nice, I needed to pad the sentences to make sure the list of sentences contained an equal number of words per sentence. (I just zero-padded them.)

If you pad the input, both `3rd Approach` and `4th Approach` should work.

Comment: This was the answer to my very similar problem.

Comment: How can I set the padding ?

Comment: @user5520049: There are probably many ways but, for a 3-dimensional input, I use `np.zeros((max_dim1, max_dim2, max_dim3), dtype=np.float32)` to create the batch space and then iterate over the input adding `results[sample_i:sample_i + sample_x_len, sample_y:sample_y + sample_y_len, 0:sample_feature_len] = sample`. I hope this helps.